# Is the past perfect correct here?

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

From a movie. Two cyclists talking after a short race.

A: How is that for slow?
B: You gotta give me a second chance! I'll race you through the tunnel.
A: You're on. Hadn't had enough? (meaning I outraced you.)

Why is it "hadn't had enough?" It only happened 10 seconds ago. Why not "didn't have enough" or "haven't had enough"?

Comment: Maybe it's meaningful in the context of the movie, but I don't understand what "How is that for slow?" means here. Are both conversants native speakers of English?

Comment: Americans. The first one said that the other one couldn't cycle fast. So, the other one decided to demonstrate how fast they can ride. And they said "How is that for slow?"

Comment: Sorry, but that's not my kind of English. But as for using Past Perfect instead of Present Perfect ***Haven't** [you] had enough?* is probably a subtitle / transcription error of a mishearing. *That* kind of mistake isn't something native speakers would ever be likely to make, no matter how "sloppy" their speech is in general.

Comment: Neither is mine. The movie is "The car" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Car

Comment: In that case the people who wrote the subtitles also misheard it.